# How to know if there's a vertical asymptote in an equation? For instance, $y=\frac{x-7}{(x-7)(x-5)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to know if there's a vertical asymptote in an equation?

For example, $$y=\frac{x-7}{(x-7)(x-5)}$$

- I know that $x=7$ is a hole. I know that holes cancel out.
- I know to find vertical asymptotes, you set the denominator equal to $0$ and solve for $x$.

But what about the (x-7)? If I set that to zero, wouldn't there be a vertical asymptote at $x=5$ AND $x=7$?

I'm just confused.

Comment: suppose $x = 7.000000000000000000000000001$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that
$$  \frac{(x-7)}{(x-7)(x-5)} = \frac{x-7}{x-7} \cdot \frac{1}{x-5}  \text{.}  $$
The factor $\frac{x-7}{x-7}$ is $1$ everywhere it is defined (which is everywhere except at $x = 7$).  So the graph of this function is the graph of $\frac{1}{x-5}$ except for punching out a hole at $x =7$.

You seem to have a handle on the graph of $\frac{1}{x-5}$.

Comment: How do I find the y-coordinate for the hole? I know the x-coordinate is x=7. But how do I find y when x=7?

Comment: "the graph of this function is the graph of $\frac{1}{x-5}$ except for punching out a hole ..."  So, the hole is at $\left( 7 , \frac{1}{7-5} \right) = (7,1/2)$.

Comment: Can something be a hole AND a VA at the same time?                                                          For example, y=3(x-3)(x+2)/4(x-3)(x+3)   I know that there's a hole at x=3. But are there two vertical asymptotes at x=3,-3 also?

Comment: @Dylan : Yes.  $\frac{x-7}{x-7} \cdot \frac{1}{x-7}$.  But note that a VA is already a point where the function is not defined, so this kind of "hole" does not alter the graph at all.

Comment: Is there any vertical asymptote in this function? y=x-3/(x+4)(x-3), x>1

Comment: @Dylan : No.  The VA would be at $x = -4$, but that is not in the given domain.  I don't understand why you are still having trouble with this.